# Confusion on a Question concerning PIDs and Zero Divisors

Tags: proof-verification, ring-theory

I'm working on the following problem:

> Show that Theorem 16.4 is false for any commutative ring that has
>   a zero divisor.

Theorem 16.4 reads:

> If $F$ is a field, $F[x]$ is a principle ideal domain.

I'm confused about how to show the claim. I "want" to do the following:

> Suppose $I[x]$ is principle ideal in $F[x]$. Then choose the polynomial of smallest degree in $I[x]$ and write: $I[x] = \langle g(x) \rangle$. Consider an $f(x) \in I[x]$. By division algorithm, we have $f(x) = g(x)q(x)+r(x)$. Note: $\text{deg }r(x)< \text{deg }g(x)$. Since zero divisors may exists, $g(x)q(x)$ may equal zero. Then $r(x) \in I[x]$. But this cannot be because $g(x)$ is the smallest degree polynomial that generates I[x]. $\blacksquare$

Is this proof correct? The statement of the problem makes this confusing. I'm essentially assuming I have a field where zero divisors exist -- this makes no sense by definition. But without assuming the field, I have no division algorithm to work with. Am I proving the right thing?

Comment: You are not proving the right thing.  They want you to prove "if $R$ is a ring with zero divisors then $R[x]$ is not a PID."

Comment: Also, if $R$ has zero divisors, doesn't $R[x]$ as well?  This is likely a problem if you want it to be a PID (emphasis on the "D").

Comment: It's not precisely worded; I guess they expect you to infer what they mean. Strictly speaking, the theorem "If F is a field, F[x] is a principle ideal domain." is true if F is a ring; all statements of the form "If A then B" are true if A is false. So to make the problem statement make sense, one can infer that what they mean is "If the word 'field' in Theorem 16.4 were replaced with 'ring', then any commutative ring with a zero divisor would be a counterexample".

Comment: Also, the term is "principal ideal", not "principle ideal".

Comment: @Randall I have $R$ has zero divisors, implies there exists $fg \in R[x]$ s.t deg($fg$) < deg($f$) + deg($g$). I'm having trouble seeing that this implies $fg$ has a zero divisor.

Comment: @yoshi  If $a, b \in R$ are zero divisors, they are still zero divisors in $R[x]$ as constant polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

You should write $I$, not $I[x]$. And don't start your proof by assuming $I$ is a principal ideal! Just assume $I$ is an ideal (and work toward the conclusion that $I$ is a principal ideal).

To be complete, you should separate out the case $I=\{0\}$ (in this case $I$ is the principal ideal $\langle 0 \rangle$), and the other case $I \neq \{0\}$, and let $g$ be a **nonzero** polynomial of smallest degree.

You can't conclude $\deg r < \deg g$. Instead, you **can** conclude: $\deg r < \deg g$ or $r=0$.

It's correct that you want to arrive at $r \in I$. But saying ``$g(x)q(x)$ may equal zero'' is not a statement that implies $r \in I$. (Sure, $gq$ might equal zero; for instance if $q=0$. But $gq$ might *not* equal zero, and anyway so what, even if $gq=0$, how does it relate to $r \in I$? You should explain that.)

Instead, to justify $r \in I$, you can use the equation $f=gq+r$ to get $r=f-gq$. You know $f \in I$, you know $g \in I$, and you know $I$ is an ideal. From there, you should be able to complete the proof that $r \in I$.

At the end of your proof, you are right, $r \in I$ and $\deg r < \deg g$ is a contradiction. The other possibility is $r=0$. So this proves $r=0$, $f = gq$, so $f \in \langle g \rangle$. Therefore $I \subseteq \langle g \rangle$.

If you want to be complete, you should also prove $\langle g \rangle \subseteq I$, but perhaps that is obvious enough to skip.

Comment: I read this question wrong -- see the comments above

Comment: Oh! Okay. Sorry, never mind.